# MS Access 2007, creating calculated field on a form, that adds data only from the active record on the current form

Tags: forms, ms-access, ms-access-2007

I am trying to add a calculated field in a form.

I want to be able to add data from various fields, but only the data that is on the active form (not all of the data for in those table columns).

(I'm used to working in excel but am relatively new to Access)... I had tried adding this formula to a txt box on the form:   =Sum([System 1 LOE]+[System 2 LOE])  however that is adding all of the numbers that are found on the table on the system 1 & 2 LOE columns, and I am only looking to add the 2 numbers that are visible on the form for the currently active record?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Sum()` sums all records, if you want only the current record, leave it out:

```
=[System 1 LOE]+[System 2 LOE]
```

Comment: Thank you... I knew it was easy!